# Does anyone have working examples of configuration files for SSRS (SQL Server Reporting Services) for custom security plugins?

Tags: reporting-services

everyone!

We're trying to implement custom security for SSRS according to Microsoft specification
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/extensions/security-extension/implementing-a-security-extension?view=sql-server-ver15

I've found sample plugin implementations:
https://github.com/qqbuby/PowerBI.ReportingServices.Extensions.git
https://github.com/microsoft/Reporting-Services.git

Examples have step by step configuration guide and even powershell script.
But all my attempts to configure SSRS for this plugin wasn't successful.
I get configuration error all the time and cannot even find the error in logs or event viewer.

If someone has implemented this approach then please show me your configuration files (stripped from passwords of course).
I'll be so happy!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Dumb. But if SSRS is not restarted from the manager then configuration is broken. Restarting ISS alone in not enough.